# Как в Laravel запустить сервис провайдер после другого сервис провайдера?

Tags: php, laravel

В сервис провайдере показывается текущий User для корректного показа которого нужно чтобы сперва запускался провайдер`App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class` а потом мой провайдер.

Как сделать запуск одного провайдера возможным только после запуска другого провайдера ?
Возможно ли  задать очередность запуска провайдеров ?

Пробовал менять очередность в файле `config / app.php`  не помогло.

Comment: зачем это нужно?

Comment: Нужно чтобы сперва авторизировался  пользователь только потом можно было его виводить

Comment: Ну так проверяйте isAuth и выводите либо политику делайте police